# How does parse response when there is more request then the limit?

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, response, backend

I am working in implementing of parse service.

Suppose we have a free account of parse. So it allow us to send 30 Request/Second.
What happen if there is 40 request sent each second.

will parse respond to 10 request after the 30 request completed or will it reject that request?
 
if it respond to 10 request after the first 30 and same thing happen for continues 2 min then we have 10 * 120 = 1200 request pending. What happen in this scenario ?

If Prase service going to reject due to this reason(like more request then the limit) then how does we get to know this reason. Is there any error code for this rejection?

Comment: There is a FAQ or forum question somewhere on the parse website. Anyway, after the limit it will reject any additional calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this post:
https://parse.com/questions/getting-this-application-has-exceeded-its-burst-limit-code-155-any-idea

seems that any additional call that exceed the burst limit, will return an error like this:

```
{"code":155,"error":"This application has exceeded its burst limit."}
```